# Как обратиться к вариативному товару в магазине?

Tags: php, wordpress, интернет-магазин, woocommerce

Привет. Магазин на woocommerce. Есть товары простые `object(WC_Product_simple)`, а есть вариативные `object(WC_Product_variable)`. как можно обратиться к вариативным и стянуть у них атрибуты?
`global $product;
if($product->..) {...}`

Answer (score 1):

все, нашел `if($product->product_type == 'variable') {...}`